Numpy: apply mask to values, then take mean, but in parallel
I have an 1d numpy array of values:
v = np.array([0, 1, 4, 0, 5])

Furthermore, I have a 2d numpy array of boolean masks (in production, there are millions of masks):
m = np.array([
    [True, True, False, False, False],
    [True, False, True, False, True],
    [True, True, True, True, True],
])

I want to apply each row from the mask to the array v, and then compute the mean of the masked values.
Expected behavior:
results = []
for mask in m:
    results.append(np.mean(v[mask]))

print(results) # [0.5, 3.0, 2.0]


Easy to do sequentially, but I am sure there is a beautiful version in parallel? One solution, that I've found:
mask = np.ones(m.shape)
mask[~m] = np.nan
np.nanmean(v * mask, axis=1) # [0.5, 3.0, 2.0]


Is there another solution, perhaps using np.ma module? I am looking for a solution that is faster than my current two solutions.

Found an answer using np.ma: np.ma.array(v * m, mask=~m).mean(axis=1).data
But still, solution is slower than I would hope for (in my case values and masks a very large).

Does you real-world array contain 5 items per row? Numpy is really not optimized for that. Is this 32-bit integer like in your example?

Note that masked arrays are generally not very efficient. They are mainly meant to be convenient in the first place. Creating temporary arrays are very expensive in this case because the operation is memory bound. Numba/Cython can help in this case but their may be clearly sub-optimal for other reasons (still certainly much faster than a naive Numpy code). Also please note that Numpy functions are not multithreaded (only BLAS functions are). Numpy functions can benefit from SIMD parallelism though.

Real world shapes might be v = (1,000,000,) and m = (10,000, 1,000,000). Memory is not an issue. And dtype is float

"Memory is not an issue" I mean that the memory bandwidth is an issue, not the memory usage. The memory bandwidth is rather limited on most mainstream platforms.

Faster Numpy code
A faster Numpy way to do that is to perform a matrix multiplication:
(m @ v) / m.sum(axis=1)

We can optimize this further by avoiding implicit conversion and perform the summation with 8-bit integer (this is safe only because v.shape[1] is small -- ie. less than 127):
(m @ v) / m.view(np.int8).sum(dtype=np.int8, axis=1)


Even faster code with Numba multithreading
We can use Numba to write a similar function and even use multiple threads:
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(float32[::1], bool_[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(v, m):
    si, sj = m.shape
    res = np.empty(si, dtype=np.float32)
    for i in nb.prange(si):
        s = np.float32(0)
        count = 0
        for j in range(sj):
            if m[i, j]:
                s += v[j]
                count += 1
        if count > 0:
            res[i] = s / count
        else:
            res[i] = np.nan
    return res


Results
Here are results on my i5-9600KF CPU (with 6 cores):
Initial vectorized code:   136 ms
jakevdp's solution:         74 ms
Numpy matmul:               28 ms
Numba sequential code:      21 ms
Optimized Numpy matmul:     20 ms   <-----
Numba parallel code:         4 ms   <-----

The sequential Numba implementation is unfortunately not much better than the Numpy one (Numba do not generate a very good code in this case), but it scale well so the parallel version is significantly faster.
The Numba parallel version is 34 times faster than the initial vectorized code and 18 times faster than the jakevdp's solution. The Numpy optimized matrix-multiplication-based solution is 3.7 times faster jakevdp's solution.
Note that the Numba code is also a bit better than the jakevdp's solution and the optimized Numpy one since it support the case where the mean is invalid (NaN) without printing a warning about a division by 0.

I think the cleanest vectorized approach would be something like this:
result = np.broadcast_to(v, m.shape).mean(axis=1, where=m)

However, this does involve explicitly broadcasting v to the shape of m, so depending on memory constraints it may not be optimal.

Nice one, this is the fastest for now! Memory is not an issue

broadcasting makes views, so doesn't hurt memory use.
